# Present Perfect, Past Simple and Past Perfect Continuous

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> We were late because we 1) ***had/have had***  some car problems. By the time we
>   got to the train Susan 2) ***had been waiting/was waiting*** for us for more
>   than two hours.

1) The correct answer is **have had** because we don't specify the time the action was taken?

2) The correct answer is **had been waiting** because we emphasise to the duration of the action?

Sorry for asking silly questions.

Comment: What is the question your asking?

Comment: Am I completing correctly the gaps?